# Display QProgressDialog based on swifter apply current percentage

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5, swifter

For my PyQT5 application I am performing a large DataFrame swifter apply which can take a small period of time. During this time my application displays a "(Not responding)" message in the window title bar.

While the swifter apply is running in the background - within the console this is shown:
[image: Swifter percentage bar output]

Is it possible to extract the current percentage from swifter and pass it to a percentage bar?

Simplistic version of code (has progress bar but its just displayed from range loop):

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QProgressDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import swifter



class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100, 70)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
        #swifter call below stops gui with high computation and would like to extract percentage from.
        df['A'] = df.A.swifter.progress_bar(True).apply(getx) 
        self.progress_bar()

    def progress_bar(self):
        percentage = QProgressDialog(self)
        percentage.show()
        for x in range(0,100):
            percentage.setValue(x+1)
        percentage.close()

def getx(x):
    x = np.random.randint(0, 100000)
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use swifter?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes it is required